# Cordova Plugin From Git Reference In Controller

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, apache-cordova

I'm building my project in Visual Studio with the Apache Cordova Ionic (tabs) project template. I have installed [this plugin](https://github.com/BlueFletch/cordova-plugin-honeywell-captuvo) via the `config.xml` interface just fine (it seems). However I'm having troubles accessing the plugin via a controller.

```
 .controller("DashCtrl", function ($scope) {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(navigator.captuvo);
    }
})
```

That is showing `undefined` in the console.

I'm still learning Ionic and the cordova system, so it's probably something simple I am missing.

I have added the Camera plugin and `navigator.camera` is resolving fine.

Comment: Are you running it on the device or in your browser? Plugins aren't available in the browser.

Comment: Browser. How do you get around this during dev? Some kind of try/catch? Or strictly dev on the device?

Comment: If you use ngCordova, it has stubs available for when you're in your browser.  Typically, the answer is to check where you're running and if you're running in the browser than don't load the plugin.

Comment: Or you can simply verify if the plugin exists with `typeof navigator.captuvo != "undefined"`